# Building address fields from the "address_components" in Google maps API?

Tags: google-maps

Google API geocode service works well for me when there is only one match with the address my system is processing.  When there are two or more matches I would like to present the addresses found (perhaps the "formatted_address") to the user and let them choose which one they want.

However Google returns many field "types".  So I'm wondering how to build an address (fields) out of the different types of data, by concatenating the appropriate "address_components".  I am interested in splitting up the address into separate fields (street address, town / city, country and postal code) to store it on a database.  Is there a page that explains which types to use and in which order?

For example I am thinking of using "street_number", "route" and "locality" for the street address part, which would work for a typical address, but I know that it won't always work.  So I'm looking for a robust, but not necessarily an exhaustive solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've came across the Google Geocoding Response Object and there is no easy way to handle that. But regarding a PHP Solution I've created a custom Controller which is suited for Laravel but can be adapt to any other PHP Application without hussle.

You can find the full gist here: https://gist.github.com/Gkiokan/510a04aadaeed911958cb17b6e62a38f

Now for your answer on how to get the data sorted out of the Google Geocoding Response Object. You need to loop though the `address_components` Array and save the needen value to a new Object or Array. You can find the corresponding Method for filtering the Data on Line 43 @ Method `getAddress`. [here](https://gist.github.com/Gkiokan/510a04aadaeed911958cb17b6e62a38f#file-googlegeocodingcontroller-php-L43)

A seperated Solution would be as following:

```
    // some php file 
    public function getAddress($response=[]){
        // get the address_components Array here
        $ac = $response['results'][0]['address_components'];

        // predefine the final $address Array
        $address = [
          'address'   => '',
          'city'      => '',
          'postal_code' => '',
          'country'   => '',
          'formatted' => $response['results'][0]['formatted_address'],
        ];

        // Loop though the address_components and set matching values
        foreach($ac as $item):
            $name = $item['long_name']; 
            $type = $item['types'][0];

            switch ($type):
                case 'route':
                  $address['address'] = $name;
                break;

                case 'locality':
                  $address['city'] = $name;
                break;

                case 'postal_code':
                  $address['postal_code'] = $name;
                break;

                case 'country':
                  $address['country'] = $name;
                break;

            endswitch;
        endforeach;

        return $address;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the api docs: under `formatted_address`

> Do not parse the formatted address programmatically. Instead you should use the individual address components, which the API response includes in addition to the formatted address field.

[Link to quoted docs.][1]
[1]: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Please parse your address elements from the `address_components` section of the getDetails response. Find the docs for that at the same location.

Comment: As a note: You can add a condition for each value if it's not there. Check to see if type: "postal_code" is there, parse if it is, return empty string if not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet from inside a php function which uses a for/next loop to extract the address components.  It could be expanded for the ones of interest to you.

```
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
//  

        foreach($parsed_json['results'] [0] ['address_components'] as $a){
            if($a ['types'] [0] == 'postal_code') $zipcode = $a ['long_name'];
            if($a ['types'] [0] == 'locality') $city = $a ['long_name'];
            if($a ['types'] [0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') $state = $a ['short_name'];   
            }
```